# How can I set Google voice typing as the default text input in my app?

Tags: android, android-input-method

How can I set Google Voice typing as the default text input in my app?

Also, how can I ensure that Google Voice Typing is enabled when my app is installed and started?

Comment: "How can I set Google Voice typing as the default text input in my app?" -- you don't. The user chooses the input method, not you, because it is the user's device, not yours. The user can choose whatever input method the user wants, from a built-in soft keyboard to a third-party soft keyboard to a Bluetooth hardware keyboard to whatever. You cannot force the user to use Google's keyboard, let alone voice input.

Comment: Can I not set the default input method also?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings - General Management - Language and input - On-screen keyboard, and turn off the voice typing keyboard (for me it was Samsung voice typing) that you don't want to use. If you only have one, i.e. Google voice typing, that will become your default.